# Python Keras Prediction returning nan

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am having problems with understanding how Keras works with data and why my model is not working accordingly. I am trying to build small model that could predict cities based on input of longitude and latitude.

What i would like to see is when i make a prediction, for example, the first index of cities array i would like to see the output array index zero to have largest activation value.

**My current model with Keras & Tensorflow**

**Data**
The latitude and longitude data is normalized between 0 / 1

```
cities = [];

cities.append([60.1695213,24.9354496]); #1
cities.append([60.2052002,24.6522007]); #2
cities.append([61.4991112,23.7871208]); #3
cities.append([64.222176,27.72785]);    #4
cities.append([60.4514809,22.2686901]); #5
cities.append([65.0123596,25.4681606]); #6
cities.append([60.9826698,25.6615105]); #7
cities.append([62.8923798,27.6770306]); #8
cities.append([62.2414703,25.7208805]); #9
cities.append([61.4833298,21.7833309]); #10
cities.append([61.0587082,28.1887093]); #11
cities.append([63.0960007,21.6157703]); #12
cities.append([60.4664001,26.9458199]); #13
cities.append([62.601181,29.7631607]); #14
cities.append([60.9959602,24.4643402]); #15
cities.append([60.3923302,25.6650696]); #16
cities.append([61.6885681,27.2722702]); #17
cities.append([65.579287,24.196943]); #18
cities.append([65.986503,28.692848]); #19
cities.append([61.1272392,21.5112705]); #20

train_cities = np.array(cities);

for i in train_cities:
    i[0] = normalize(i[0],65.986503,60.1695213,0.99,0.01)
    i[1] = normalize(i[1],29.7631607,21.5112705,0.99,0.01)

train_labels = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
```

**Normalized longitude/latitude**

```
[[0.01168472 0.41784541]
 [0.01769563 0.38420658]
 [0.23568373 0.28146911]
 [0.69444458 0.74947275]
 [0.05918709 0.10113927]
 [0.82756859 0.48111052]
 [0.14867768 0.50407289]
 [0.47041082 0.7434374 ]
 [0.36075063 0.51112371]
 [0.233025   0.04349768]
 [0.16148804 0.80420471]
 [0.50471529 0.02359807]
 [0.06170056 0.65659833]
 [0.42135191 0.99118761]
 [0.15091674 0.36189614]
 [0.04922184 0.50449557]
 [0.26760196 0.69536778]
 [0.92308013 0.33013987]
 [0.99168472 0.86407655]
 [0.17303361 0.01118761]]
```

**Model**

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape = (2,)),
    keras.layers.Dense(20, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
]);

model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_cities, train_labels, epochs=50)
```

**Prediction**

```
model.fit(train_cities, train_labels, epochs=50)
```

What i would like to do with this data is simply input one of the cities index array to the network and get the corresponding label for it.

I am getting a output array of nan indexes

```
array([[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]], dtype=float32)
```

Also it seems that the network is not actually learning for reasons that i cant figure out.

```
Epoch 50/50
20/20 [==============================] - 0s 200us/step - loss: nan - acc: 0.0000e+00
```

Any help would be a appreciated.

Normalisation function

```
def normalize(value,maxValue,minValue,maxRange,minRange):
    return ((value - (minValue - 0.01)) * (maxRange - (minRange))) / ((maxValue - 0.01) - (minValue - 0.01)) + (minRange)
```

Comment: where `normalize` function comes from? looks like int not usual from `sklearn.preprocessing import normalize`

Comment: Normalizing function is something that i have written my self to get values between 0 / 1. I added the code for the post.

Comment: Now in 2022 with python3.9.6, tensorflow2.7.0 and keras2.7.0 I have to use an array as train_labels, a list of integers does not work any more. I used `train_labels = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19])` in order to get the program running.

Comment: The code line below the heading "Prediction" is incorrect. It should be something like: `Y_all = model.predict(train_cities); print("Y_all = "+str(Y_all)); index = np.argmax(Y_all,axis=1); print("predicted labels = "+str(index))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not clear what is `train_labels`. If it's the same as `labels` then you'll need to have output of the last layer to be `21` and not `20`, since in keras labels start from `0`. Or you can redefine your labels to be from `0` to `19`. Otherwise your code is ok and it's working on my pc. I've got `100%` accuracy after `~1900` epochs

Comment: Yes, train_labels = labels, i wasn't sure if it needed to be numpy array or just normal python array format, i forgot put that into the description. Ah now i see what the problem was then, i didn't realize that the labels values should start from 0 also.

Comment: I think it's not important if you use np.array or just standard python list as an input for keras. Both will work